# Triangle angle calculation knowing only one angle

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle

I have two GPS positions and i want to calculate the angle between the one GPS point and a third point that i'm estimating it location with reference to the second GPS point. The Figure below explains the problem which is calculating `angle(Alpha)` in the figure. Here is what i know. first I calculated the heading of point A `Heading (A)` -- initial angle bearing, using old and new GPS coordinate of point A-- then I found the bearing angle from point A to B `BeraingAngle(AB,AF)`.Now since both handing and bearing angle are relive to the north then `Angle(Beta)=angle(AB,BF)= abs(Heading(A)-BearingAngle(AB,AF))`. Also using haversine method i computed the distance two GPS point A and B `dist(A,B)`. now I know the distance between point B and C`dist(B,C)` and the `angle(Theta)`angle(BC,BE). So is it possible to calculate angle(Alpha) `angle(AC,AD)`.

**Example**

- Heading (A) =270 degrees, Bearing (A,B) =300 degrees, Hence **Angle
  (Beta)=300-270=30 degrees**
- **dist (A,B)= 15 meters**
- **dist(B,C)=5 meters**
- **angle(Theta)=7 degrees**

**Note that BE is parallel to FD and BF is parallel to ED**

[image]

Comment: i really dont understand what we know from the  figure

Comment: It would be very nice if you can just sum up all the known and unknowns in an ordered way.

Comment: You say you have a figure but you didn't add it?

Comment: I have updated the figure, Thanks a lot

Comment: It would be helpful if you proofread the OP and make edits.

Comment: Thanks Xpw for mentioning that, I mixed up angles names.Now it is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proof by pictures:
[image]
`Renaming some variables`
[image]
`taking components of a`
[image]
`taking components of b`
[image]
`as opposite sides in rectangle are equal`
[image]
*There is a typo in the picture above, in the right upper corner it is $b \cos(c)$ and not $b\cos(d)$

`rewriting`
[image]
Can you handle now?

Comment: Thank you, I was almost there figuring it out .Yes , It is Arctan (CD/AD)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have enough information.  The line $DEC$ could slide to the right with $C$ rising to keep $\theta$ constant.  There is nothing that constrains it.  Similarly $BF$ can slide either direction without causing a problem.

Comment: I have updated the figure to show what is know and what is not. Would you please explain in more details.

Comment: i know the length of AB and BC. if i can find the length of AD and DC i can find `angle(alpha)` right?